# I lost my Admin password and i need to find out what it is

Tags: 12.04

I've tried to type something that is my most favorite stuff or what names i could have put.
I need to learn how to hack into my admin account or just reset the password some how.

Comment: Is your home directory encryped? If so your chances are decreasing. I'd boot with a live CD and see what can be seen.

Comment: A simple search on this site would have got you [the answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Comment: this sounds like somebody trying to get into someone else's computer ;)

Answer (score 1):

you can change the old password via Grub

If you have a single-boot (Ubuntu is the only operating system on your computer), to get the boot menu to show, you have to hold down the Shift key during bootup

If you have a dual-boot (Ubuntu is installed next to Windows, another Linux operating system, or Mac OS X; and you choose at boot time which operating system to boot into), the boot menu should appear without the need to hold down the shift key

From the boot menu, select recovery mode, which is usually the second boot option.

After you select recovery mode and wait for all the boot-up processes to finish, you'll be presented with a few options. In this case, you want the Drop to root shell prompt option so press the Down arrow to get to that option, and then press Enter to select it

Once you're at the root shell prompt, if you have forgotten your username as well, type ls /home (small letters & not capitals). This will list all the user accounts in your set up.

To reset the password, type passwd username where username is the username you want to reset eg. passwd mysterio in my case

You'll then be prompted for a new password. When you type the password you will get no visual response acknowledging your typing. Your password is still being accepted. Just type the password and hit Enter when you're done. You'll be prompted to retype the password. Do so and hit Enter again.

Now the password should be reset. Type exit to return to the recovery menu.

After you get back to the recovery menu, select resume normal boot, and use Ubuntu as you normally would—only this time, you actually know the password!

Hope this helps. Sorry I couldn't add images as I'm on my phone